# Repeating JavaScript function and returning to initial callback?

Tags: javascript, function, callback

**Is it possible** to call a function in JavaScript **that calls itself** again, **and** after it calls itself again, **finally runs the initial callback function?**

I will explain what I mean in code...

```
//on page load
getProviderNextAppointment(null, function(nextAppointment) {

    otherFunction(); //<----- how can I always end up back here, no matter what?

});


//getProviderNextAppointment function
function getProviderNextAppointment(startDate, callback) {

    getNextAppointment('provider', startDate, function(data) {

        //if provider has schedule
        if(!$.isEmptyObject(data.AllProviders)) {

            //set provider params
            //nextAppointment = data.x

            //callback
            if(typeof callback === 'function') {
                return callback(nextAppointment); //callback from call on page load
            }

        } else {

            if(data.ErrorCode !== 'StartDateTooFarInFuture') {

                /*---------->
                 * this is where we this function calls itself again;
                 * but when it hits the callback above (provider
                 * has schedule), or when it hits the callback
                 * below (last group of appointments), it
                 * should run the initial callback to
                 * execute otherFunction()
                 <----------*/
                getProvidersNextAppointment(data.LatestDate);

            } else { //hit last group of appointments

                if(typeof callback === 'function') {
                    return callback(null); //callback from call on page load
                }

            }

        }

    });

}
```

I did not include `getNextAppointment()` function, because it is irrelevant to the question. Just know that it is calling an API that is returning the appointment information, as well as a `LatestDate` property that we are using as the `startDate` for the next API call. We are also looking for a response for the `ErrorCode` property that says it's the end of the results, so that we are not looping forever.

Comment: It is not clear to me what you are asking. It would be more helpful if you would describe which higher level requirement you are trying to solve, providing the input and the output you expect for it.

Comment: @trincot, you got in your answer. That's exactly what I needed to do—keep the reference to my initial callback function and pass it through for recursion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to keep a reference to the initial callback function, then you could just pass it on via the recursive call.

Change the recursive call from this:

```
getProvidersNextAppointment(data.LatestDate);
```

to:

```
getProvidersNextAppointment(data.LatestDate, callback);
```

Now the nested function context will have a reference to the original callback function, and this could in theory cascade further down the recursion tree until the callback function is finally executed.

Comment: Yes, this is absolutely how to do it! Not sure why I did not think of this. Of course it's passing the same callback function through and through. Thanks!